# DSC used to configure GPO?

Tags: windows, powershell, dsc, gpo

Would it be possible to use DSC to configure GPOs? For example, to add a new GPO or edit an existing GPO.

As I understand, there seems to be no such discussion around.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't have any experience with DSC, so take this with a grain of salt... But GPO is a different animal than DSC, and are used for different things to accomplish similar results. I'm 99% sure you can't do this. I'm not saying it's impossible. Just seems like a weird thing to try to mush together.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. For example, Daniel Snelling's "GroupPolicyDsc" module in the PowerShell Gallery (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/GroupPolicyDsc).

The PowerShell Team also has a "GPRegistryPolicy" module (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/GPRegistryPolicy) used for synchronization of Group Policy filesystem files to and from registry settings.